# How to create an app that has floating views on to of others

Tags: android, android-view

How to create an app that has a floating view all over the others, and always stays at the top. Is it an open activity, If so how to crate a such view?

similat to how its done in the following app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=genius.mohammad.floating.stickies&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You need a transparent activity.

Create a style.xml inside values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
...
</activity>
```

Use a FrameLayout to let those views float and overlap.
To change views on top. use bringToFront() method for view.
Those views can be LinearLayout that contains ImageView, TextViews and may also contain FrameLayouts. you can also get use of the background property for those controls.

Comment: And what should I do do it won't go when I press home or open another app?

Comment: That's another thing those are widgets. as far as I know.

Comment: I don't think it's a widget, it only appears when you open the app (and stays until you close with the x), and it's placed wherever you want on the screen, not as other widgets.  And stays on top of other open activities

Comment: If you are sure. then you do it the same way. what is missing now is how to keep them on top of everything.

Comment: How not allowed, I've added an app that does it as an example

Comment: Does what? keep your app on top of every other app. since you have it. why are you asking.